# How outsource Electron menu code from main.js to separate menu.js?

Tags: electron

The Electron menu code in my main.js is now really long.
Is it possible to outsource it to another file?
If yes would I still be able to call the functions which are located in main.js from the menu?

```js
// MENU BEGIN
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const { app, Menu } = require('electron')

const isMac = process.platform === 'darwin'
const isWin = process.platform === 'win32'

const template = [
    // { role: 'appMenu' }
    ...(isMac ? [{
        label: app.name,
        submenu: [
            { role: 'about' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'services' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'hide' },
            { role: 'hideOthers' },
            { role: 'unhide' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'quit' }
        ]
    }] : []),
    // more menu code...
    {
        role: 'help',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Learn More',
                click: async () => {
                    const { shell } = require('electron')
                    await shell.openExternal('https://github.com/aronsommer/eddy-g')
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MENU END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the size of your Electron application grows, it is imperative that you begin to separate your code into their own files. This is what is called separating your concerns. It makes for a tidy, easy to read well-structured project.

---

Separate the creation of your menu from your `main.js` file into its own file (let's call it `menu.js`) and then export it's `build()` function.

`menu.js` (main thread)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronMenu = require('electron').Menu;

const isMac = process.platform === 'darwin'
const isWin = process.platform === 'win32'

function build() {
    const template = [
        // { role: 'appMenu' }
        ...(isMac ? [{
            label: electronApp.name,
            submenu: [
                { role: 'about' },
                { type: 'separator' },
                { role: 'services' },
                { type: 'separator' },
                { role: 'hide' },
                { role: 'hideOthers' },
                { role: 'unhide' },
                { type: 'separator' },
                { role: 'quit' }
            ]
        }] : []),
        // more menu code...
        {
            role: 'help',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'Learn More',
                    click: async () => {
                        const { shell } = require('electron')
                        await shell.openExternal('https://github.com/aronsommer/eddy-g')
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    
    electronMenu.setApplicationMenu(electronMenu.buildFromTemplate(template));
}

// Export the publicly available function
module.exports = {build};
```

---

Now, in your `main.js` file, require it as you would any other file, and then call the `build()` function once the application is `ready`.

> Note: I have called the menu `build()` function from within the `createWindow()` function as it is really part of window creation. IE: The menu is part of a window.

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

const nodePath = require("path");

const appMenu = require('menu');

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { appMenu.build(); } // Build the menu
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

---

Regarding your question "Would I still be able to call the functions which are located in main.js from the menu?".

The answer is yes, if you `require` those function at the top of your `menu.js` file.

If you do not want to `require` all those functions from within your `menu.js` file, you could require Node's events module and on a menu `click`, `emit` an event and listen for it within your other script(s). This design allows for a very modular application, allowing new features to be added at a later date with no  difficulty at all.

---

## Bonus

Having the building of your menu in a separate file also allows you to update (re-build) your menu dynamically should any menu items need changing.

`menu.js` (main thread)

```js
// Rebuild the menu on localisation change.
appEvents.on('locale:changed', () => {
    appMenu.build();
});
```