# Import Menu() from a .js file in a different folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Look I know this is a mild repost of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71678884/how-outsource-electron-menu-code-from-main-js-to-separate-menu-js) but its a bit outdated and I have diffrent packages to worry about aswell as diffrent formatting in my file and file system

I am new to electron so I am sorry if this is a really stupid question
What would be the current best practice for importing Menu() from `./Core/components/Menubar.js`

`Menubar.js`

```js
const { app, Menu } = require('electron')

const isMac = process.platform === 'darwin'

const template = [
  // { role: 'appMenu' }
  ...(isMac ? [{
    label: app.name,
    submenu: [
      { role: 'about' },
      { type: 'separator' },
      { role: 'services' },
      { type: 'separator' },
      { role: 'hide' },
      { role: 'hideOthers' },
      { role: 'unhide' },
      { type: 'separator' },
      { role: 'quit' }
    ]
  }] : []),
  // { role: 'fileMenu' }
  {
    label: 'File',
    submenu: [
      isMac ? { role: 'close' } : { role: 'quit' }
    ]
  },
  // { role: 'editMenu' }
  {
    label: 'Edit',
    submenu: [
      { role: 'undo' },
      { role: 'redo' },
      { type: 'separator' },
      { role: 'cut' },
      { role: 'copy' },
      { role: 'paste' },
      ...(isMac ? [
        { role: 'pasteAndMatchStyle' },
        { role: 'delete' },
        { role: 'selectAll' },
        { type: 'separator' },
        {
          label: 'Speech',
          submenu: [
            { role: 'startSpeaking' },
            { role: 'stopSpeaking' }
          ]
        }
      ] : [
        { role: 'delete' },
        { type: 'separator' },
        { role: 'selectAll' }
      ])
    ]
  },
  // { role: 'viewMenu' }
  {
    label: 'View',
    submenu: [
      { role: 'reload' },
      { role: 'forceReload' },
      { role: 'toggleDevTools' },
      { type: 'separator' },
      { role: 'resetZoom' },
      { role: 'zoomIn' },
      { role: 'zoomOut' },
      { type: 'separator' },
      { role: 'togglefullscreen' }
    ]
  },
  // { role: 'windowMenu' }
  {
    label: 'Window',
    submenu: [
      { role: 'minimize' },
      { role: 'zoom' },
      ...(isMac ? [
        { type: 'separator' },
        { role: 'front' },
        { type: 'separator' },
        { role: 'window' }
      ] : [
        { role: 'close' }
      ])
    ]
  },
  {
    role: 'help',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Learn More',
        click: async () => {
          const { shell } = require('electron')
          await shell.openExternal('https://electronjs.org')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]


const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)

// Export the publicly available function
```

`Main.js`

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, nativeImage, NativeImage, nativeTheme, dialog, Menu } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

//Start the node file system
const fs = require('fs')


const https = require('https')

const appMenu = require('menu');

//Chart JS testing and config
const Chart = require('chart.js');

const MenuConfig = require("./Core/components/Menubar.js")

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });

  win.loadFile('index.html')


dialog.showOpenDialogSync ([BrowserWindow,])
//Dark theme config
  ipcMain.handle('dark-mode:toggle', () => {
    if (nativeTheme.shouldUseDarkColors) {
      nativeTheme.themeSource = 'light'
    } else {
      nativeTheme.themeSource = 'dark'
    }
    return nativeTheme.shouldUseDarkColors
  })

  ipcMain.handle('dark-mode:system', () => {
    nativeTheme.themeSource = 'system'
  })
}

const iconName = path.join(__dirname, 'iconForDragAndDrop.png');
const icon = fs.createWriteStream(iconName);

// Create a new file to copy - you can also copy existing files.
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'drag-and-drop-1.md'), '# First file to test drag and drop')
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'drag-and-drop-2.md'), '# Second file to test drag and drop')

https.get('https://img.icons8.com/ios/452/drag-and-drop.png', (response) => {
  response.pipe(icon);
});




ipcMain.on('ondragstart', (event, filePath) => {
  event.sender.startDrag({
    file: path.join(__dirname, filePath),
    icon: iconName,
  })
})

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

I tried to use require() and build() but I can't get the syntax right for this context

Comment: If you get a error message or stack trace, or compilation error message, please [edit] to include it.

Comment: For any other people that find this, this was a poorly made template on my part [Please refer here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For anyone else that comes across this here is how I fixed it assuming `template` is configured properly.

**In Menubar.js**

`module.exports = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);` On the last line if you set up your template

**In main.js**

At the top of the file after requiring electron

```js
const applicationMenu = require('./Menubar');
```

On the line where you are calling `app.whenReady`

```js
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(applicationMenu);
  createWindow()
  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})
```